# How can I dynamically reference column names while looping through a query's results?

Tags: sql, coldfusion, cfml

I have successfully written a `SELECT` statement that uses dynamic variables. It uses variables from the page to know what columns to select from a big, messy table. It looks something like this.

```
<cfquery name="getCapabilityAndDescription" datasource="Stuff">
SELECT [EntryID],
<cfloop list="#JobLevelList#" index="JobLevelIndex">
   [#getJobDesc.Type##JobLevelIndex#Capability],
   [#getJobDesc.Type##JobLevelIndex#Description],
</cfloop>
[JobID]
FROM [JobCapabilityMatrix]
WHERE JobID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#URL.JobID#">
AND SkillID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#URL.SkillID#">
</cfquery>
```

Say for example, it dynamically selects a column called `Baker3Description`.

But...How would I be able to output that dynamically? I guess to sum it up, I need to create a dynamic variable and then put it in a query's scope.

So far I have tried setting it and calling it like this:

```
<cfset DescriptionVariable = #JobTitle# & #JobLevelIndex# & 'Description'>
<cfoutput>
#getCapabilityAndDescription.DescriptionVariable#
</cfoutput>
```

But it doesn't evaluate the way I want it to, and just tells me

> Element DESCRIPTIONVARIABLE is undefined in
> GETCAPABILITYANDDESCRIPTION.

I know there's a way to actually return the content of `Baker3Description` from the query, maybe using array syntax? But I've messed around too much and need a little help. Please & thanks.

Comment: Yes, there is, but it requires a row number too. General syntax is i.e. `#queryName[ "columnName" ][ rowNum ]#` https://trycf.com/gist/65ff8f56d1b5ea670c13aecbe0528506/acf2021?theme=monokai . Though be careful  building that kind of dynamic sql since it can also be a sql injection risk depending on the source of the values.

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks!

Comment: You can get a list of the columns by doing `queryName.columnlist`. This will return a comma delimited list of selected columns.

Comment: True. One difference between them is columnList always returns columns in alphabetical while getMetaData returns the select list order of the query.

Comment: @SOS you sent me down a path that led to a pretty quick resolution. If you want to post your comment in the form of a fleshed out answer, the holy green checkmark is yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible using structure notation, but also requires a query row number. The general syntax is

```
#queryName[ "columnName" ][ rowNum ]# 
<!--- 
.. or specifically 
--->
#getCapabilityAndDescription[ DescriptionVariable ][ 1 ]#
```

To output all of the query columns dynamically. Use [GetMetaData()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/getmetadata.html) to retrieve an array of query column properties (in `select` order). Then use the `name` property to output each column value:

```
<!--- Demo query --->
<cfset yourQuery = queryNew("EntryID,Baker3Description"
        , "integer,varchar"
        , [[1,"Descrip A"],[2,"Descrip B"]]
    )>

<cfset meta = getMetaData(yourQuery)>
<cfoutput query="yourQuery">
    <cfloop array="#meta#" index="props">
        #yourQuery[props.name][currentRow]#
    </cfloop>
    <br>
</cfoutput>
```

**Though be careful building that kind of dynamic sql**. If any of the values used to build the column names are user supplied (for example `getJobDesc.Type`) the query will be vulnerable to [second order sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Second_order_SQL_injection).